# g++ doesn't recognize the option -wl

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, makefile

I'm working on Ubuntu 12.10 with gcc version 4.7.2.

I'm trying to make the following makefile:

```
CC = g++
CCFLAGS = -fPIC -O3 -Wall -ffast-math -msse -msse2 -fopenmp
LINKFLAGS = -shared -Wl -fopenmp -lgomp

INPUT = im2col.cpp fastpool.cpp local_response_normalization.cpp neuron.cpp
TARGET = libcpputil.so

# If we are going to use MKL, we include additional flags
MKL_FLAGS = -D DECAF_USE_MKL
MKL_LINK_FLAGS = -lmkl_rt

all: $(INPUT)
    $(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) $(INPUT)
    $(CC) $(LINKFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) *.o
all_mkl: $(INPUT)
    $(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) $(MKL_FLAGS) $(INPUT)
    $(CC) $(LINKFLAGS) $(MKL_LINK_FLAGS) -o $(TARGET) *.o
speedtest_lrn: speedtest_lrn.cpp local_response_normalization.cpp
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -lgomp -o speedtest_lrn speedtest_lrn.cpp local_response_normalization.cpp
clean:
    rm *.so
    rm *.o
```

But somehow g++ doesn't recognize the option -wl. Here's the error that I'm getting:

```
make -C layers/cpp/
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/decaf-release-master/decaf/layers/cpp'
g++ -c -fPIC -O3 -Wall -ffast-math -msse -msse2 -fopenmp im2col.cpp fastpool.cpp local_response_normalization.cpp neuron.cpp
g++ -shared -Wl -fopenmp -lgomp -o libcpputil.so *.o
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wl’
make[1]: *** [all] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/decaf-release-master/decaf/layers/cpp'
make: *** [all] Error 2
Failed to build the C libraries; exiting
```

**EDIT**: When I try to remove the "-wl" I get:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/decaf-release-master$ python setup.py 
make -C layers/cpp/
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/decaf-release-master/decaf/layers/cpp'
g++ -c -fPIC -O3 -Wall -ffast-math -msse -msse2 -fopenmp im2col.cpp fastpool.cpp local_response_normalization.cpp neuron.cpp
g++ -shared -fopenmp -lgomp -o libcpputil.so *.o

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/decaf-release-master/decaf/layers/cpp'
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
```

It somehow worked when I tried it on Ubuntu 12.04 and gcc 4.7.7.

Can someone please explain what's the problem and how can I fix it?

Thanks,
Gil.

Comment: I don't remember seeing `-Wl` as an option. What is the intended meaning of it, why do you pass it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the manual:

> -Wl,option
>       Pass option as an option to the linker. If option contains commas, it is split into multiple options at the commas. You can use this
>   syntax to pass an argument to the option. For example,
>   -Wl,-Map,output.map passes -Map output.map to the linker. When using the GNU linker, you can also get the same effect with
>   -Wl,-Map=output.map.

so, you miss the options for -Wl.

Comment: +1 good to know; here's [the link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) if someone's interested. Similarly `-Wp,option` is for preprocessor and `-Wa,option` for assembler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got this makefile from a package I downloaded. Is it same to just remove the -Wl ?

Comment: Try to remove it ... If it's not performing as expected come back here :) We'll fix it!

Comment: Thanks, I tried to remove it and it didn't work, please see the edit to my question.

Comment: Hm, he second error is not related to make and gcc, it has to do with the `setup.py` which came with the package you are trying to run. Your compilation was successfull.

Comment: From the decaf site, use it like: `python setup.py build` or `python setup.py install` ... you just run `python setup.py`